# Confused about a corollary in MIT.Introduction.to.Algorithms(CLRS), seek help

Tags: algorithms, hash-tables, hashing

### Desc'

I was reading CLRS Book's chapter 11 *Hash Tables*, and encountering some problems.

There is an corollary in CLRS book, in Page 275 (quoted on the bottom of post), which discussed the expected number of probes on a unsuccessful search, given open-address hash table.
I think the proof is strongly convincing, and I have no problems about it. But the following corollaries, starting from ***With probability approximately, the first probe finds an occupied slot, so that w...***, confuses me. Is it a really intuitive interpretation? I mean, this bound has nothing to do with these corollaries, we can directly get those corollaries without the bound $\frac{1}{1-\alpha} = 1+\alpha+\alpha^2...$, that is, if the probability bound of $\{X \geq i\}$ is $\alpha^2$, then $i$ should be $3$, from:

[image]

$i==3$ means the $1$st, $2$nd slots probed both are occupied, and we are going to probe the third one. Is this exactly what ***"With probability approximately $\alpha^2$, the first two slots are occupied so that we make a third probe,"*** is talking about? If it is, then why author treats it as a **intuitive interpretation** from that expected number bound???

So confused, could anyone help me out?

---

### Quotes

Text:

> This bound of .... has an intuitive interpretation. We always make the first probe. With probability approximately ..., the first probe finds an occupied slot, so that we need to probe a second time. With probability approximately ..., the first two slots are occupied so that we make a third probe, and so on...

original:
[image]

Comment: (You can use $L^AT_EX$: $1/(1-\alpha) = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 +\cdots$: `$1/(1-\alpha) = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 +\cdots$`.)(check your spelling checker)

Comment: Is this exactly what "With probability approximately $α^2$, the first two slots are occupied so that we make a third probe," is talking about? : Yes I guess. `If it is, then why author treats it as a intuitive interpretation from that expected number bound???`: The author is not treating "with probability at most $\alpha^{i-1}$ we make $i$ probes in the hash table" as an intuitive interpretation from the expectation formulation (the G.P. series). Rather the authors consider it the other way round. The authors are trying to intuitively justify the expectation formulation, based on $P(\#probes)$

Comment: @Abhishek Ghosh what a rigorous correction, appreciate that :)   In terms of question itself, still confused... In fact , I was trying to figure out some relations between the formula $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 +\cdots$ and corollary `We always...third probe`, some relations that the author aims to reveal. Are the relations below? : the 1st item means the $Pr\{p_1\ occurred\}=1$, then we have bound value $1$, which means the first probe must occur, similarly, the 2nd item $\alpha \implies Pr\{p_2\ occurred\}=\alpha$(approximately), the 3rd one $\alpha^2 \implies Pr\{p_3\ occurred\}=\alpha^2$, etc.

Comment: @liguuu I do not get what do you mean by $p_1$ , $p_2$ etc... But anyways I give you the idea... $E[x]\approx 1+\alpha+\alpha^2+...$ What is the intuition behind this? For the first probe, we are bound to make it. So its probability is $1$ (and we have the first term). We make the second probe only if the first probe fails. The first probe fails with probability $Pr\{X\geq 2\} \approx \alpha$ [and we get the 2nd term $1.\alpha=\alpha$ where the $1$ accounts for the probe]. We make the 3rd probe when the first two probes fail and it happens with probability $\Pr\{X\geq 3\} \approx \alpha ^2$